# Python: getting an needs bytes not str on a Requests put

Tags: python, request, put

We use Interact as our intranet vendor. I am trying to use their API to update the review date on some of the pages. Each session requires the user to get a token and then use that token for auth on other commands. That works fine, I can get the token and read stuff through the API. But when I try to use PUT to update pages I get this error message which looks like it is being generated from one of the libraries that the Request module is using.

```
Error with updating page data...
memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 998, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1233, in sendall
with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Here's my relevant code:

```
def updatePages(dictPages):

    for pageId in dictPages:

         dictPage = dictPages[pageId]
         jsonPage = json.dumps(dictPage, indent = 4) 
         print(jsonPage)
    
         strURL = rootURL + "api/page/" + pageId + "/composer"
    
         dictHeader = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", "accept": "application/json", "X-Tenant":tenantGuid, "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
        try:
             response = requests.put(strURL, data={jsonPage}, headers=dictHeader)
             print(response.json())

        except Exception as e: 
             print("Error with updating page data...")
             print(e)
             print(traceback.format_exc())

        break
```

here's the json I am sending (which I've filtered through a lint)

```
{
     "Transition": {
         "State": "published",
         "Message": "Updating the review date"
     },
     "Page": {
         "ContentType": "html",
         "TopSectionIds": 4070,
         "AuthorId": 449,
         "Title": "How to refer a candidate to an open position",
         "Summary": "Help Recruit a Talented Individual and Collect a Bonus.",
         "Features": {
             "DefaultToFullWidth": true,
             "AllowComments": true,
             "IsKeyPage": false,
             "Recommends": {
                 "Show": true,
                 "MaxContentAge": 7
             }
         },
        "PubStartDate": "2022-09-20T20:31:12.3+00:00",
        "PubEndDate": "2025-09-20T09:00:00.0000000Z",
        "ReviewDate": "2023-03-20T09:00:00.0000000Z",
        "TagIds": [],
        "Keywords": []
     }
 }
```

Full traceback

```
Error with updating page data...
memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 998, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1233, in sendall
with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
 TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/Projects/Intranet/Development/updateReviewDate.py", line 133, in updatePages
response = requests.put(strURL, data={jsonPage}, headers=dictHeader)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 130, in put
return request("put", url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1076, in _send_output
self.send(chunk)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1002, in send
self.sock.sendall(d)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1233, in sendall
with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
 TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Do I have to convert the dictionary to binary data?

Comment: Use `json=dictPage`, not `data={jsonPage}`

Comment: Thanks, that cleared that error.  Make it an answer and I'll give you the bump.